# Pourquoi la tournure « persuader de ce que » est-elle incorrecte ?

Tags: grammaire

Je suis débutant en langue française.

L'entrée *[persuader](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/persuader/59826#difficulte)* du Larousse dit :

> **Recommandation** : Éviter dans tous les cas la tournure incorrecte *persuader de ce que.

Pourquoi est-il  grammaticalement incorrect de dire « persuader de ce que » ?

Quand est-ce qu'il est incorrect de changer « de ce que » en « que » ou « que » en « de ce que » ?

Par exemple, vous pouvez dire « surpris que » et « surpris de ce que ». Pourquoi ces formes sont-elles grammaticalement correctes alors que  « persuader de ce que » ne l'est pas ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL. Peux-tu donner un exemple de phrase où on t'a dit que *persuader de ce que* n'est pas grammaticalement correct ? Il y a des fois où on ne peut pas dire autrement, et d'autres fois où ce n'est pas recommandé mais on le trouve quand même fréquemment, et dans des textes en très bon français. Ce serait donc mieux que tu proposes un contexte.

Comment: merci pour la bienvenue. S'il vous plait, regardez "https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/persuader/59826#difficulte". Il dire que: « recommandation : Éviter dans tous les cas la tournure incorrecte *persuader de ce que. ».

Comment: « Persuader-dé de ce que » : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=persuader+de+ce+que%2Cpersuad%C3%A9+de+ce+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3# existe, malheureusement Googole ne donne plus les sources, mais la tournure est peu utilisée :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=persuader+de+ce+que%2Cpersuad%C3%A9+de+ce+que%2C+persuader&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersuader%20de%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersuad%C3%A9%20de%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersuader%3B%2Cc0

Comment: En écoutant cet orateur, on  ***se** persuade de ce qu'il* faut faire. Le dictionnaire cité n'est pas une référence pour les recherches littéraires.

Comment: @Personne Votre exemple ne contient pas la locution conjonctive de subordination « de ce que ». « ce qu'il faut faire est une proposition nominale (se persuader de la nécessité de faire quelque chose.)

Comment: @LPH — Mes oreilles sont incapables d'entendre les concepts sectaires que vous apportez, ma francophonie primitive et viscérale est définitivement incompatible avec l'académisme grammairien éthéré … 14f6A21 (débutant, comme il le précise) pourra toujours utiliser mon commentaire — tout à fait correct nonobstant les recommandations dictionnairiques — comme il l'entend.

Comment: @Personne Vous ne rejetez pas la grammaire en bloc… Si ?

Comment: @LPH … Si : la grammaire vient après que l'exemple ait été expliqué, c'est ainsi que je n'ai rien à faire du nouveau jargon que l'on enseigne doctement aux enfants actuellement. Il y a peu de règles à connaître, quelques mots charnières ainsi que le mode de fonctionnement des exceptions pour que la logique sujet-verbe-complément fonctionne. Le reste se découvre à la lecture des textes, se vérifie avec un vrai dico. Alors, que le concept « P = GS + GV + (GC) » fasse les délices de la Faculté transgénique hors sol de nos grandes cités, dénote des savoirs abstraits …

Comment: … connus de personnes qui ré-inventent la roue à l'identique et restent incapables d'enseigner dans les cités alentours à des enfants qui ne sont pas comme elles … et je reste imperméable à la grammaire en étant incapable de qualifier les mots et la structure des phrases que je vient d'écrire.

Comment: @Personne Je suis d'accord sur un point, mais avec une réserve: à la condition de lire beaucoup de livres bien écrits, le français n'offre plus de secrets sur le plan d'une identification sûre de la forme au contexte ; la grammaire  toute seule ne produira jamais cela qu'à un  degré dérisoire.  Ma conviction personnelle reste cependant qu'il faut allier à un exercice important de lecture un exercice d'écriture (et d'élocution et d'écoute) mais sans négliger l'approche structurelle, c'est à dire la grammaire, qui met en valeur la logique internalisée,   //  (1/3)

Comment: @Personne celle-ci restant inaccessible sans l'explication de grammaire. //  Vous semblez faire  référence à la nouvelle terminologie officielle, celle que l'on trouve à partir de ce lien-ci: https://www.ac-paris.fr/portail/jcms/p2_2125483/livre-terminologie-grammaticale-web-1308526?details=true  Il me semble que leur approche fasse preuve d'un effort dans la recherche d'une structure vrai, mais je suis incapable de déceler la logique dans leur nouvelle pratique d'association des prépositions au compléments, et ils n'expliquent rien à ce sujet. // (2/3)

Comment: @Personne  Votre vocabulaire (transgénique, hors-sol) laisse à penser que vous voyez en les garants de la langue pas plus qu'une faune domestique aliénée et manipulée ; vous semblez avoir beaucoup à dire… (3/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il ne faut pas utiliser « persuader de ce que » lorsque « de ce que » est compris dans le sens de la locution conjonctive.

> [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/persuader/59826) Éviter dans tous les cas la tournure incorrecte *persuader de ce que.

Ce dictionnaire ne mentionne pas la nature des mots dans la combinaison « de ce que » mais il ne s'agit que de la locution conjonctive. Cette construction ne se trouve pas dans les livres Googol, c'est à dire pratiquement pas.

On la trouve une fois en 1950 et même encore récemment, une fois en 2013, mais c'est tout.

([réf. 1950](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22persuad%C3%A9s%20de%20ce%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) Persuadés de ce que la culture ne saurait constituer pour personne un avoir mais une dette , les membres de la Société Européenne de culture entendent agir ...

([réf. 2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Meilleure_des_vies_Eloge_de_la_vie_no/4uwNOAgYJgkC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22persuader+de+ce+que%22&pg=PT75&printsec=frontcover)) .. il a souhaité les persuader de ce que l'homme tend à voir ce qu'il désire dans ce qui est là, et que savoir et ne pas savoir ont affaire au désir plutôt ...

- <s>Elle les a persuadés **de ce que** ce travail n'était pas pour eux.</s>
- Elle les a persuadés **que** ce travail n'était pas pour eux.

Lorsque « que » est considéré comme étant un pronom relatif, évidemment, le remplacement ne serait pas correct. Certaines sources considèrent que le pronom est « ce que », mais ce n'est qu'une question de différence de point de vue des grammairiens.

- Elle les a persuadés de ce que  personne ne pouvait leur faire croire. (*pronom relatif*)

On ne voit la différence entre la locution conjonctive et la locution dans laquelle « que » est un pronom qu'à partir du sens de la portion de phrase qui suit, ce qui rend difficile la tâche de déterminer  ce dont il s'agit.

« De ce que » est une locution conjonctive que l'on peut encore trouver par exemple, après le nom « avis » et le verbe « aviser », mais dans les livres du 19ième siècle et avant.

- avis de ce que ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avis)) , aviser de ce que ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aviser)).

Cependant la grammaire normative enseigne, encore une fois, qu'il vaut mieux employer « que » pour ce verbe.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aviser)) Rem. 1. La gramm. normative enseigne qu'on doit employer *aviser que* de préférence à *aviser de ce que* (cf. Hanse 1949, Thomas 1956, Colin 1971).

La situation n'est pas différente pour « surpris de ce que ». On n'en trouve très peu dans le siècle dernier. On dit uniquement « surpris que » de nos jours. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22surpris%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

Comment: je vous remercie pour rendre chose plus claire.specialement pour faire la difference entre « locution conjonctive » et « pronom relatif ».

Answer (score 3):

En principe *de ce que* ne doit être employé que quand la proposition exprime une cause et que le verbe de la principale est employé avec un complément d'objet.

Exemple [pris ici](https://grammaire.reverso.net/de-ce-que-que/) :

> La direction a félicité l'équipe commerciale de ce que les chiffres de vente aient atteint de tels résultats.
> (féliciter est ici construit avec un COD : l'équipe commerciale. La proposition complément exprime elle la cause, la raison pour laquelle  la direction a félicité l'équipe).

effectivement dans ce cas on ne peut pas employer autre chose que *de ce que* pour introduire la subordonnée. Il en va de même avec une phrase comme :

> je suis persuadé de ce que je fais.

Regardons maintenant les cas où il n'y a pas de complément d'objet dans la principale :

Le dictionnaire [Larousse dit](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/persuader/59826) :

> Éviter dans tous les cas la tournure incorrecte *persuader de ce que.

Mais ne dit pas en quoi elle serait incorrecte et ne donne aucun exemple.

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition) ne mentionne pas *persuader de ce que* mais par contre mentionne à propos d'*informer de ce que* (§ 975, 4.),

> *Informer de ce que* n'est pas, semble-t-il, reçu par le bon usage. Dites : informer que [...].
> J'ai l'honneur de vous informer que je ne monterai plus jamais en course. (Jules Supervielle)

Les cas d'*informer* et de *persuader* sont pour moi semblables et on peut les rapprocher.

Ceci n'empêche pas de rencontrer les exemples qui suivent (et il est possible d'en trouver d'autres) dans des textes bien écrits :

> on tentera de vous persuader de ce que cette question est complexe ([une plaidoirie d'avocat](https://www.cairn.info/revue-journal-du-droit-des-jeunes-2011-6-page-41.htm?contenu=resume))

> Pour se persuader de ce que les lendemains du 11 janvier n'ont pas empêché...  ([une chronique](https://www.lefigaro.fr/vox/politique/2015/11/17/31001-20151117ARTFIG00158-goldnadel-trente-ans-de-complaisance-envers-la-radicalite-islamiste.php) par un avocat-écrivain)

> Tu essayais de te persuader de ce que le changement te plaisait. ([Dolorès, une histoire de cigarette](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Ailleurs_du_temps/Fk_WGuf0IzwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22persuader%20de%20ce%20que%22&pg=PT62&printsec=frontcover), [Marcel Brion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Brion)

Les puristes « du bon usage » trouveraient les trois citations ci-dessus fautives. Mais ceux qui pensent que la langue est une matière vivante ne sont pas gênés par cette construction.

Comment: Peut-on écrire "persuadé par qqn ou qlq chose" ? Par exemple: "Je ne suis persuadé par votre... "

Comment: « Je suis persuadé de ce que je fais. » : il ne s'agit plus de la conjonction « de ce que » mais du pronom relatif « ce que », qui introduit une proposition nominale (se persuader de qqc (ce que je fais)). Ce n'est plus la même chose.

Comment: @LPH Nous sommes bien d'accord, c'est pour ça que je différencie nettement les cas.

Comment: C'est très vague : avant cette phrase  vous parlez de la locution conjonctive et sans aucun avertissement vous passez à une locution qui contient un pronom relatif. On ne peut être sûr de rien avec cette analyse.

Comment: @LPH je me garderai bien de faire des analyses. Je lis, je regarde, je constate, je rapporte. Les analyses en ce domaine je les laisse aux linguistes.

Comment: C'est une bonne approche, elle a ses mérites, mais on apprend la grammaire pour rendre les choses plus claires, il ne faut pas la négliger.

Comment: @MichelT Je ne suis pas sûre de comprendre *je ne suis pas persuadé par votre raisonnement* par exemple ?

Comment: Oui, c'est ça.... est-ce grammaticalement correct ?

Comment: @MichelT *Je ne suis pas persuadé par votre raisonnement* est  parfaitement correct.

Comment: merci pour vos réponse, spécialement @None je vous remercie d'avoir m'aider mais je n'ai pas un savoir profond comme vous en langue francaise. alors j'ai besoin que la grammaire rempli mon manque du savoir profond.

Comment: @14f6A21 Dans le cas de *persuader de ce que*  il n'est pas question de grammaire, il n'y a pas de règle (Larousse et les grammaires ne donnent pas de règle) c'est une question d'usage, c'est à dire de préférence. Mais ce qui fait une langue c'est aussi l'usage, et dire que quelque chose n'est pas correct alors que c'est utilisé par beaucoup, c'est exprimer une opinion, pas donner une règle.